# Copy & paste a cell along with its name in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, copy-paste

Is there a way to copy a cell that also has a "name", and paste it somewhere else so that the new cell also has the same "name"?

Answer (score 1):

This VBA code copies all the nakms from active workbook to destination.  Not quite sure what your trying to do but this should get you started:

```
Sub Copy_All_Defined_Names()
   ' Loop through all of the defined names in the active
   ' workbook.
     For Each x In ActiveWorkbook.Names
      Workbooks("Destination.xls").Names.Add Name:=x.Name, _
         RefersTo:=x.Value
   Next x
End Sub
```

From here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213389

Comment: thanks guys, sorry didn't realise i was at the wrong place, thanks for the info all the same :)